# How can I select a list inside a focused list item with CSS?

Tags: html, css, select, html-lists

I want to do that if user focus "`<li><a href="#">Kurumsal</a></li>`", then opacity of ul that inside of li will be 1.

Like this: https://i.hizliresim.com/slkl93w.jpg
Screenshot:

[image: enter link description here]

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Kurumsal</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Hakkımızda</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Vizyon ve Misyon</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Kurucumuz</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Markalarımız</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Kalite, Çevre ve İş Sağlığı Güvenliği</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: But someone used it like this: [link](https://i.hizliresim.com/slkl93w.jpg) and screenshot: [link](https://i.hizliresim.com/nu2ylfm.jpg)

Comment: I just formatted your code. Is that last `<ul>` supposed to be `</ul>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `focus` and `focus-within` and if you want mouse interaction add in `hover`

```css
ul ul {
  opacity: .2;
  transition: opacity .5s;
}

ul a:hover + ul, 
ul a:focus + ul, 
ul ul:hover,
ul ul:focus-within {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Kurumsal</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Hakkımızda</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Vizyon ve Misyon</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Kurucumuz</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Markalarımız</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Kalite, Çevre ve İş Sağlığı Güvenliği</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Kurumsal</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Hakkımızda</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Vizyon ve Misyon</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Kurucumuz</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Markalarımız</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Kalite, Çevre ve İş Sağlığı Güvenliği</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>  
</ul>
```